# PHP + SQL, correct tre with parent and child category and item

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, categories

I'm trying to show the correct tree of data but I'm, stock, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I've tried both with PHP code and pure SQL code, let me first show what I've tried so far.

```
public function supported($ids) {
        
        $arr = json_decode($ids, true);
        
        $STH = $this->dbh->query("SELECT cid,device FROM supported_devices WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$arr).")");
        
        $a = $STH->fetchAll();
        
        if(count($a)) {
            
            foreach($a as $b) {
                $newArr[] = $b['cid'];
            }
            
            $STH = $this->dbh->query("SELECT cid,cat_name FROM supported_devices_cats WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$newArr).")");

            $c = $STH->fetchAll();
            
            foreach($c as $d) {
                $newArr2[] = $d['cid'];
            }
            
            $STH = $this->dbh->query("SELECT cat_name FROM supported_devices_cats WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$newArr2).")");

            $e = $STH->fetchAll();
            
            foreach($e as $parent) {
                $return[] = $parent['cat_name'];
                foreach($c as $child) {
                    $return[] = $child['cat_name'];
                    foreach($a as $device) {
                        $return[] = $device['device'];
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return $return;
            
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM supported_devices_cats c
    LEFT JOIN supported_devices_cats pc
    ON c.id = pc.cid
WHERE
    c.cid IS NOT NULL 
    OR (c.cid IS NULL
       AND pc.cid IS NULL)
```

[image: Category table]
[image: device table]

I'm trying to make so the parent category is shown first, then all child categories after where the right device is under each child category. I'm not sure how else I can explain it, I've added a painted picture, maybe that explains better what I'm trying to do.

update, I need to upgrade my MySQL server to a higher version.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure why you need a column "cid" in the table supported_devices. Just the id is enough for foreign key.

Having said that, here is what I used as database schema and test content:

```
CREATE DATABASE cats_devs;

USE cats_devs

CREATE TABLE supported_devices_cats(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    cid INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES supported_devices_cats(id),
    cat_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    dt DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE TABLE supported_devices(
    id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES supported_devices_cats(id),
    device VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    dt DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

INSERT INTO supported_devices_cats(id, cid, cat_name) VALUES
(1, NULL, "Disk Drives"), (2, NULL, "Monitors"),
(3, 1, "SSD"), (4, 1, "HDD"), 
(5, 2, "TN"), (6, 2, "IPS");

INSERT INTO supported_devices(id, device) VALUES
(4, "Seagate 2TB"), (4, "WD 2TB"),
(3, "Corsair 256GB"), (3, "WD 256GB"),
(5, "ASUS 27in"), (5, "ASUS 21in"),
(6, "Viewsonic 27in"), (6, "LG 24in");
```

What I do next is a CTE recursive query (available in the newer MySQL/MariaDB servers - for older version an equivalent with SELF JOIN will be needed):

```
WITH RECURSIVE hier_query(id, cat_id, cat_name, dev_name, dt) AS(
    SELECT id, cid, cat_name, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(128)), dt
    FROM supported_devices_cats
    WHERE cid IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT supported_devices_cats.id, supported_devices_cats.cid, 
           supported_devices_cats.cat_name, supported_devices.device, supported_devices_cats.dt
    FROM supported_devices_cats
    JOIN hier_query
         ON hier_query.id = supported_devices_cats.cid
    LEFT JOIN supported_devices ON supported_devices.id = supported_devices_cats.id
)
SELECT id, cat_id, cat_name, dev_name, dt
FROM hier_query;
```

This will produce the following result which contains all required information:

```
+------+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id   | cat_id | cat_name    | dev_name       | dt                  |
+------+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
|    1 |   NULL | Disk Drives | NULL           | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    2 |   NULL | Monitors    | NULL           | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    3 |      1 | SSD         | Corsair 256GB  | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    3 |      1 | SSD         | WD 256GB       | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    4 |      1 | HDD         | Seagate 2TB    | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    4 |      1 | HDD         | WD 2TB         | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    5 |      2 | TN          | ASUS 27in      | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    5 |      2 | TN          | ASUS 21in      | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    6 |      2 | IPS         | Viewsonic 27in | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    6 |      2 | IPS         | LG 24in        | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
+------+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Now in this result table when dev_name is NULL, it's a parent category. You can fetch all parent categories from it that way. Then for every parent category you can find the child when you compare id to cat_id. Finally you can get all devices easily.

Honestly I tried to make it an "all SQL" solution, but I struggled to sort that table in the way you wanted. I bet that somebody else will be able to do it better.

P.S. Here is a quick dirty hack for the sorting issue. I concat the main category before the child name with "->" separator. That way you can split them easily later.

```
WITH RECURSIVE hier_query(id, cat_id, cat_name, dev_name, dt) AS(
    SELECT id, cid, cat_name, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(128)), dt
    FROM supported_devices_cats
    WHERE cid IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT supported_devices_cats.id, supported_devices_cats.cid, 
           CONCAT(hier_query.cat_name, "->", supported_devices_cats.cat_name), 
           supported_devices.device, supported_devices_cats.dt
    FROM supported_devices_cats
    JOIN hier_query
         ON hier_query.id = supported_devices_cats.cid
    LEFT JOIN supported_devices ON supported_devices.id = supported_devices_cats.id
)
SELECT id, cat_id, cat_name, dev_name, dt
FROM hier_query
ORDER BY cat_name;
```

produces:

```
+------+--------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id   | cat_id | cat_name         | dev_name       | dt                  |
+------+--------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
|    1 |   NULL | Disk Drives      | NULL           | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    4 |      1 | Disk Drives->HDD | Seagate 2TB    | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    4 |      1 | Disk Drives->HDD | WD 2TB         | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    3 |      1 | Disk Drives->SSD | Corsair 256GB  | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    3 |      1 | Disk Drives->SSD | WD 256GB       | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    2 |   NULL | Monitors         | NULL           | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    6 |      2 | Monitors->IPS    | Viewsonic 27in | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    6 |      2 | Monitors->IPS    | LG 24in        | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    5 |      2 | Monitors->TN     | ASUS 27in      | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
|    5 |      2 | Monitors->TN     | ASUS 21in      | 2020-06-25 07:52:39 |
+------+--------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

You can even add "WHERE cat_id IS NOT NULL" condition to remove the two useless rows. All other rows contain what you need.

Comment: The cid in device table is to know which child category it belongs to. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try out this code. But yeah as you mention yourself, the correct sorting is still missing, I hope others can give a point on how to sort it the correct way. I'll play around with your code and see what I can do with it. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: The id is also a cid as cid is FK to id :) But yeah, RDBMS and SQL are not friendly for such things.

Comment: agreed :) I normally don't have problems with my SQL and coding in general but when it   requires multiply tables and correct sorting, then my head hurt sometimes.

Comment: quick dirty hack for it: WITH RECURSIVE hier_query(id, cat_id, cat_name, dev_name, dt) AS(
  SELECT id, cid, cat_name, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(128)), dt
  FROM supported_devices_cats
  WHERE cid IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sdc.id, sdc.cid, 
      CONCAT(hier_query.cat_name, "->", sdc.cat_name), 
      supported_devices.device, sdc.dt
  FROM supported_devices_cats AS sdc
  JOIN hier_query
    ON hier_query.id = sdc.cid
  LEFT JOIN supported_devices ON supported_devices.id = sdc.id
 )
 SELECT id, cat_id, cat_name, dev_name, dt
 FROM hier_query
 ORDER BY cat_name;

Comment: Ah, it looks nasty. I will edit the answer and add it as addition there.

Comment: Awesome mate ! I'm getting an error tho: https://gyazo.com/9ffe0c1da34d397817f7a4eb13dda7b8 - I've never used the WITH statement, so not sure what causes the error.

Comment: For WITH statements with CTE you must use MySQL 8.0+ or 10.2.1+.

Comment: Ah okay, I see.. Just check my version: https://gyazo.com/4b9e9ce66c924ef65c4cf32832e68295 - Ubuntu seems to be way behind in their repo.